Como puedo pasar una imagen de un formulario a php?
agradeceria si pueden ayudar a mi problema en estos momentos. Estoy creando un formulario que tiene un drag and drop donde agregas una imagen para enviarla al controller de mi php (laravel), se que no puedo modificar el input:file por tema de seguridad, asi que en el momento en que suelto la imagen lo lee perfecto, pero al enviarlo con un ajax a mi controller ahi es donde ni lee la imagen ni nada referente a eso, muestro mi JS para que lo vean y despues agrego mi HTML.
JS - HTML:


'use strict';
const drop = document.querySelector(".container-input");
const form = document.querySelector(".enviar");
let imageData;

function verificarArchivo(url, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('HEAD', url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                callback(true); // El archivo existe
            } else {
                callback(false); // El archivo no existe o hay un error
            }
        }
    };

    xhr.send();
}

function dropHandle(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    let data = e.dataTransfer.files[0];

    const validExtensions = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/png', 'image/gif'];

    if(validExtensions.includes(data.type)){
        verificarArchivo("/image/imgProduct/" + data.name, function(existe) {
            if (!existe) {
                imageData = data;
                let file = new FileReader();
                file.readAsDataURL(data);
                console.log(file)
            }
        });
    }
    
}

function dragOverHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    // Evita que se envíe el formulario de forma predeterminada
    e.preventDefault();

    // Crea un objeto FormData con los datos del formulario
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    // Obtiene el método y la acción del formulario
    const method = form.getAttribute('method');
    const action = form.getAttribute('action');

    // Si hay información de la imagen disponible, agregarla al FormData
    if (imageData) {
        // Agregar el Blob al FormData
        formData.append('image_file', imageData);
    }

    // Configura las opciones de la solicitud
    const options = { 
        method: method,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'no-cache',
        body: formData,
    };

    // Realiza la solicitud fetch con los datos del formulario
    fetch(action, options)
        .then(response => {
            // Verifica si la respuesta fue exitosa
            if (response.ok) {
                // Devuelve el cuerpo de la respuesta como texto
                return response.text();
            }
            return response
        })
        .then(data => {
            // Maneja los datos de la respuesta
            console.log(data);
        })
});
<form class="edit-product enviar" action="{{route('admin.product.update')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$datos->producto_ID}}">
 <label for="image">imagen</label>
 <div class="container-input" ondrop="dropHandle(event)" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
  <input type="file" name="image" id="img" class="inputfile inputfile-1" value="" onchange="previewImage(event)">
  <label for="img" id="message">Seleccionar archivo</label>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label for="name">Nombre</label>
 <input type="text" name="name" value="{{$datos->producto_name}}" required>
  </div>
  <div>
 <label for="descripcion">Descripcion</label>
 <textarea type="text" name="descripcion" cols="30" rows="10" required>{{$datos->producto_descripcion}}</textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
  <label for="precio">Precio</label>
  <input type="number" name="precio" value="{{$datos->producto_price}}" required>
   </div>
   <div>
  <label for="genero">Genero</label>
  <input type="text" name="genero" value="{{$datos->producto_genero}}" required>
   </div>
   <div>
  <label for="stock">Stock</label>
 <input type="number" name="stock" value="{{$datos->producto_stock}}" required>
   </div>
   <div>
  <label for="proveedor">Proveedor</label>
  <input type="text" name="proveedor" value="{{$datos->producto_proveedor}}" required>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="btn_actualizar">Actualizar</button>
</form>



Esto es todo mi cofigo, espero que puedan ayudarme con este problema, no soy el mejor programando asi que si ven un error agradeceria que me ayuden a mejorar.
